# Name a variable with a different variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables

My goal is to name a new variable with the content/string of a different variable.

```
function foo(id) {
    var example + id; // So basically add the id to the example variable making something like example1 etc...
}

foo(1)

example1 = "text"
console.log(example1) // And it logs "text"
```

Hope that explains it and that you can give a good response thanks!

Comment: too lazy to look for the dupe.... Use an Object or an Array.... do not create more variables

Comment: Any time you find yourself wanting variables dynamically named "something1", "something2", "something3", and so on then what you really want is called an "array".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an associative array:

```
var something=[];
something["example" + 1] = "hello"

console.log(something["example1"]) => "hello"
```

Comment: should use an object, not an array

Comment: Yes, that is one option. Beginners understand arrays more easily than objects.

Comment: I would like to here about the object way, if possible...
Im not actually that beginner in web development theres just a few things i haven't either used in a while or even got to learning!

Comment: It's almost the same code. Just replace the first line with `var something = {};`.

Comment: It's just that in javascript, an array is also an object. So the tend to have some behavior in common (like accepting a string in a `[]` operator).

Comment: "Beginners understand arrays more easily than objects." I can open a window with a hammer, it works, but it is not really the test tool for the job.